# How to keep a thread alive in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a windows service that is designed to handle incoming data, process it, and alert users if necessary. One thing that I am having trouble figuring out is how to keep a thread alive.

I have a few classes that share a `ConcurrentBag` of `Device` objects. The `DeviceManager` class is tasked with populating this collection and updating the device objects if a parameter about a device changes in the database. So for example, in the database someone updates device 23 to have a normal high of 50F. The `DeviceManager` would update the appropriate device in memory to have this new value.

Oracle provides an event handler to be notified when a table changes ([docs here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/changenotification/ChangeNotification.htm)). I want to attach an event handler so I can be notified when to update my devices in memory. The problem is, how can I create a thread for my `DeviceManager` to work in and for it to just idle in the thread until the event occurs and is handled there? I would like to have the event fire and be handled in this thread instead of the main one.

Comment: Why do you need a single thread? Can't you take the events wherever they come?

Comment: @usr I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I wanting the devices to be managed in that thread for simplicity sake?

Comment: That's a valid reason. You then need to marshal the events to that thread. It is probably still easier to have a global lock and process events under that lock. No need for another thread.

Comment: Another option would be to implement a ThreadPool so you do not need to control your thread, and you can just request the ThreadPool to complete the task as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate worker thread when your service starts up. The worker thread will connect to the database and listen for change notifications, and update your ConcurrentBag accordingly. When the service is shut down, you can gracefully terminate the thread.

MSDN has an example that I think will help you: [How to: Create and Terminate Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: A thread cannot listen for events. The nature of an event is that someone else controls where the handler runs.

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of synchronization techniques available in .NET, and to discuss the entire scope would be too broad to address here. However, you should look at the `Monitor` class, with its `Wait()` and `Pulse()` methods.

For example:

```
private readonly object _lockObj = new object();

public void StartThread()
{
    new Thread(ThreadProc).Start();
}

public void SignalThread()
{
    lock (_lockObj)
    {
        // Initialize some data that the thread will use here...

        // Then signal the thread
        Monitor.Pulse(_lockObj);
    }
}

private void ThreadProc()
{
    lock (_lockObj)
    {
        // Wait for the signal
        Monitor.Wait(_lockObj);

        // Here, use data initialized by the other thread
    }
}
```

Of course you can put the thread's locking/waiting code in a loop if you need for the thread to repeat the operation.

It looks like there's no shortage of other questions involving the Monitor class on SO:
[https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+monitor+pulse+wait](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D%20monitor%20pulse%20wait)

And of course, the documentation on MSDN has other examples as well.